# Previously opened files don't stay open when I restart Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Whenever I close and open my Android Studio, the XML/Java files I had open previously do not restore automatically. I know this is something I've most likely messed up in the Settings, but I'm not entirely sure what it is. If someone could tell me that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings and check **Reopen last project on startup**

Comment: I have that checked already. My problem isn't that the project isn't reopening, it's that the files within the project aren't.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but it might be helpful to someone. I recently faced the same issue - the java files, that were opened in the project, didn't reopen after restarting Android Studio. It turned out that in workspace.xml (located in the .idea folder of the project) the paths to that files were incorrect. After correcting them everything worked fine again.